# Select worksheet in Excel add-in to run VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have created an add-in using VBA which is a workbook with calculations. The add-in has a userform to extract relevant information from access database and populates the workbook. After the data is populated, calculations are performed in Sheet1. I need to paste the worksheet "Sheet1" from the add-in worksheet to a new workbook on running the add-in macro.

When I run the add-in however, the worksheet appears to be hidden so my data is not updating. I get this error:
" Run-time error '1004': Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Global' failed".

Can someone tell me how to work with an add-in which has a worksheet where the required calculations are performed?

The intriguing part is when I load the add-in after removing it from the list of add-ins in excel, it runs perfectly. But when I re-run the macro, the worksheet becomes hidden, so the same error appears. I am fairly new to VBA so any suggestions would be appreciated!

***Edit***

Code:

```
Private Sub OptionOK_Click() 'On selecting OK from userform
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True 
  Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 

 'User Form Validation 
  If Trim(Me.cboData.value) = "" Then 
    Me.cboData.SetFocus 
    MsgBox "Please complete the form" 
    Exit Sub 
  End If 

 'copies data to given cell in excel     
  ws1.Range("A1").value = Me.cboData.value 

 'To copy selection from "Sheet1" into new workbook 
Workbooks("myaddin.xlam").Sheets(1).Copy 
End Sub
```

I get the error on ...> Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that I had to use "ThisWorkbook" in the add-in VBA code.

`Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets ("Sheet1")`

VBA code within a workbook should use "ThisWorkbook" to reference to sheets or ranges inside the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what sheet it is and you have access to the add-in code just make sure it's visible before the line that throws the error.

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
```

I suspect you have another problem though because you can still reference a hidden sheet in code.

---

Are you sure this line is correct:

```
Workbooks("myaddin.xlam").Sheets(1).Copy
```

Before you were referencing the name of the sheet now your referencing the position of the sheet in the workbook.

Comment: Thank you, I did try it. I have

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   
Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

I get this error: Runtime error 9, Subscript out of range. I have searched online too but I don't see any related solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. cbo is combobox in the userform. me.cboData refers to the combobox which uses access database to form a list.

Comment: Yes I believe we can reference worksheets("Sheet1") or worksheets(1). Like I mentioned, the add-in runs perfectly when I uninstall it and install it again in the excel. It hangs up on me when I run the macro after the first time.

Comment: Yes, you can but be sure that "Sheet1" is actually worksheets(1) since someone can rename it.  You could try Sheets(1).Visible = True